# Getting first image result from flickr

Tags: jquery, html, json, flickr

I have the typical example to get the first image from flickr. I call this script from a html. I use Javascript to get a value from a database, and I send that value to the html with this sentence, so it can be shown.

```
document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML=output1;
```

This is the code that I use to get the first image:

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
        $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
            tags: "clint eastwood",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        })
        .done(function( data ) {
            $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
                $( "<img/>" ).attr( "src", item.media.m ).appendTo( "#image" );
                if ( i === 0 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

How can I pass to this script the value that I have received from the database, so I can search for that tag in Flickr?

Thanks.

Comment: So you are storing your database result in #winner and you want to pass that to flickr as the tag is that correct?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, it was very difficult to explain hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to grab the HTML you have stored in #winner adn pass it to the flicker API

```
var tags = document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML;
var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON( flickerAPI, {
        tags: tags,
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    })
```

the HTML is stored in var tags and passed in the getJSON call

However if your DB call is in the same scope as your flicker call you should be able to just store and pass output1 and save the extra DOM read

Comment: Cool! I decided to put the flickr call as you said, in the same place where I call de DB. Do you know how can I delete the image of the previous search?

Comment: Yes. It fails because the .appendTo function. The image from the next search appends to the one I got from the previous search.

Comment: you could use $('#image').empty() before the appendTo call